# My EditText is cut off SMS app

Tags: java, android-layout, android-studio, android-edittext

my problem is that my text is cut :/ 
and I would like something like

[image: photo]

here is my edittext :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/tool_bar_messa"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#f4f4f4"
        android:visibility="visible">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/Contact"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:theme="@android:style/DeviceDefault.ButtonBar.AlertDialog"
            android:id="@+id/tv_toolbar"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:ellipsize="end" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvDetails"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:text="@string/Details"
            android:textColor="#3391e4"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:theme="@android:style/DeviceDefault.ButtonBar.AlertDialog" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lv_message"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:stackFromBottom="false"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_send"
        android:background="#FFF"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="46dp">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/Et_message"
            android:layout_width="294dp"
            android:hint="@string/sms_mms"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine|textCapSentences"
            android:scrollHorizontally="false"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:textCursorDrawable="@null" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnSend"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/Et_message"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/Et_message"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Et_message"
            android:background="#00ffffff"
            android:src="@drawable/btnsend" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

and this is before open keyboard then [photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y40Pz.jpg) I modify some thing about my listview to start the bottom and resize it when keyboard is open stuff like that, maybe it's the problem ?

Comment: Please could you add your photos inline so that it's easier to understand.

Comment: don't have the reputation sorry, but i think like that it's ok ?

Comment: hi, sorry I need to ask you about screenshot how your app looks before open keyboard and full content of xml. I'm pretty sure that changing one-two lines of EditText won't be enough

Answer (score 0):

just remove android:lines="2" and it solve. and you want all the lines to show then also remove android:maxLines="3".

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/Et_message"
    android:layout_width="294dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:hint="Type here"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine|textCapSentences"
    android:scrollHorizontally="false"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:maxLines="3"
    android:textCursorDrawable="@null" />
```

this is working correctly.

Comment: already try this but it doesn't work, it always like the first photo

Comment: well i guess you use it without modify `android:layout_height="match_parent"` so yes it's working but modify it by 50dp an try